# I want new user should verify his email before login

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using wp-members plugin for user registration and login. But I have to send a verification link in mail when user registers. How can I do that?

Comment: What efforts have you put to achieve this? Add some code to show the research that you've done. See [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/

Comment: Hi hemnath, I don't want that admin will approve users. I want to send an activation link to newly registered users and when they clicks that link the account will be activated.

Comment: If you do not provide a Password field for registration, then new registered users will need to check their email for the password to log in. This serves the same purpose as an activation link.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [theme my login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) so you can easily achiv this.

Require users to be approved or confirm e-mail address upon registration

one of this plugin options